# Simple convolution operation with tensorflow js

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to learn how to do simple convolution. I only want to see whether this matrix can detect v lines in images. [Like in wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_detection)

This is my MWE

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs-node"
import { readFile, writeFile } from "node:fs/promises"

async function mainModule() {

    const img = tf.node.decodeImage(await readFile("./numberOneGreyColor.png"), 1) as tf.Tensor3D;

    const tensor4d = tf.tensor4d(
       [-1, 2, -1,
        -1, 2, -1,
        -1, 2, -1,
        ], [1, 1, 3, 3])
     .cast("float32")
     .div(6)

    const result = img.div(255).conv2d(
        tensor4d as tf.Tensor4d, 1, "same") as tf.Tensor3D


    const data = await tf.node.encodePng(result)

    await writeFile("./result.png", data)
}

mainModule()
```

Which I wrote mostly by eye, so I appreciate some corrections.

Can not get this going. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think finally got it.

This is original image

[image]

And the code:

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs-node"
import { tensor3d } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-node"
import { readFile, writeFile } from "node:fs/promises"

async function mainModule() {

    let img = tf.node.decodeImage(await readFile("./images.png"), 1)
    const tensor4d = tf.tensor4d([-1, 2, -1,
    -1, 2, -1,
    -1, 2, -1,
    ], [3, 3, 1, 1]).cast("float32")

    const result = img.div(255).conv2d(tensor4d.div(6) as tf.Tensor4D, 1, "same")


    const data = await tf.node.encodePng(result.abs().mul(255))

    await writeFile("./result.png", data)
}

mainModule()
```

And the result

[image]

Not fully sure why is so dark but should inspect it later. Similar result in wikipedia by the way.